# react setState on array of objects throws 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

having problem with replacing one array of objects with another one in state

I have a function that looks like this

```
      fetch(this.state.HostUrl+'api/updateList',{
    method: "GET",
    headers:{
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(data =>  data.json())
    .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          console.log(this.state.mylist);
          this.setState({ store: data}) ;
          console.log(this.state.mylist);
          },
    (ex) => {
          this.setState({
            requestError : true
    });
      console.log('problem with input', ex)
    });
```

i'm getting an array from the server and it looks normal but as when it's running this part `this.setState({ store: data}) ;` my program returns this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Comment: can you share the output from console.log(data)

Comment: @YasserZubair if i remove my data it would look like this [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "123", objectType: "type", objectKey: "11", customName: "55", customValue: "99"}
1: ....; same as mylist in the number of columns and names; the only difference is number of objects in that array

Comment: do you use `.toString()` in your code?

Comment: the thing is, setState is asynchronous, if you try to console.log it right after setting it, you may not see your changes. Try using it like this 
`this.setState({ store: data}, () => console.log(this.state.store)) ;` 
the second argument is a function called after the state is set. If it logs the correct output you desire then problem is somewhere else

Comment: @JuniusL. yes i did, in one place  after I removed it, it wasn't necessary; that problem is gone now; thanks for the idea

Comment: @YasserZubair i didn't know that it's async function; now the state looks normal; thx

Comment: are you sure the error is thrown at the line `this.setState({store:data})`? Maybe `this.state.list` is `undefined` and `console.log` is trying to invoke a `toString()` on it?

Comment: @LincolnC i was sure that the problem is in setState but in fact it was a problem with the way I put data to a table on a page